# What is a browser's local timezone?

Tags: dart

I am using the Timezone package to create a SelectOption of available timezones in browser. The user can then select which timezone he would like any time to be display. I would like the selected option in the list to be his local time zone.

The documentation for the package indicates that variable 'local' should be the local timezone - however it always default to UTC. How can I get to be equal to the local time zone?

```
  await initializeTimeZone();
  print( local.name);
```

https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/timezone/0.4.3/timezone/timezone-library.html

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried myself but it looks like the [intl](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/intl) package might provide what you want:

```
import "package:intl/intl_browser.dart";
...
String locale = await findSystemLocale();
```

Comment: Doesnt work for me. I call 'await findSystemLocale()' but Intl.defaultLocale remains Null, Calling new DateFormat(...) then throws exception with the message 'LocaleDataException: Locale data has not been initialized, call initializeDateFormatting(<locale>).'

Comment: Call getCurrentLocale(). findSystemLocale just sets systemLocale, which is not necessarily the same as defaultLocale. But it isn't going to help you that much. findSystemLocale is just canonicalizing window.navigator.language. It will tell you a locale like en_US, but that's not a timezone.  In general, the browser knows what the local time is, but not the local timezone name. You can find the offset by asking for a local time and a UTC time, but that doesn't tell you what it's called.

Comment: Thanks, will have to rethink things a bit